# [GWT with Internet Explorer ]: FormPanel SubmitCompleteHanlder event.getResults returns null

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, formpanel

I am trying to do a `POST` operation which uploads a file.

I am using GWT 1.8 FormPanel to submit the file.

When I upload the file, server validates the file and returns response as String.

If the response code is `200`, `submitCompleteEvent.getResults()` have response text.

For example,

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
     {"message":"Invalid file!!"}
</pre>
```

But when the response code is changed to `400` in the server, `submitCompleteEvent.getResults()` returns `null`.

This is happening only in `Internet Explorer`. I am using Internet Explorer 11. For other browser, it is working fine.